# manipulating a csv file and writing its output to a new csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a simple file named saleem.csv which contains the following lines of csv information:

```
File,Run,Module,Name,,,,,  
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,nbFramesWithInterference,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,nbFramesWithoutInterference,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,nbFramesWithInterferencePartial,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,nbFramesWithoutInterferencePartial,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,nbFramesWithInterferenceDropped,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN  
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,nbFramesWithoutInterferenceDropped,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].appl,broadcast queued,3,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN  
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].appl,replies sent,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].appl,replies received,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,nominal,1.188e+07,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,total,1232.22,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,lifetime,-1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,Mean power consumption,55.7565,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,num devices,1,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,physical layer,0,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,device total (mWs),1232.22,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,account,0,1,2,3,4
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,energy (mWs),0,207.519,1024.7,0,0
General-0.sca,General-0-20160706-14:58:51-10463,MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,time (s),0,3.83442,18.2656,0,
```

I want to skip the first line, read this file and only write column[2] and column[4] to a new csv file named out.csv. I have written the following to script to do the job.

```
import csv

with open('saleem.csv') as f:
    readcsv = csv.reader(f)

    for row in readcsv:
            dele = (row[2], row[4])
            print dele
with open('out.csv', 'w+') as j:
    writecsv = csv.writer(j)
    #for row in dele:
    for row in dele:
            writecsv.writerows(dele)

f.close()
j.close()
```

This produces the following output:

```
M,y,N,e,t,w,o,r,k,.,n,o,d,e,[,4,],.,b,a,t,t,e,r,y,S,t,a,t,s
0
M,y,N,e,t,w,o,r,k,.,n,o,d,e,[,4,],.,b,a,t,t,e,r,y,S,t,a,t,s
0
```

Please help me, Sorry for the mistake previously please, as i mistakenly wrote row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edited to reflect revised question***

Some problems I can see:

P1: `writerows(...)`

```
for row in dele:
            writecsv.writerows(dele)
```

`writerows` takes a list of rows to write to the csv file. So it shouldn't be inside a loop where you iterate over all rows and attempt to write them individually.

P2: overwriting

```
for row in readcsv:
            dele = (row[2], row[4])
```

You are continuously overwriting `dele`, so you aren't going to be keeping track of `row[2]` and `row[4]` from every row.

What you could do instead:

```
dele = []
with open('saleem.csv') as f:
    readcsv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in readcsv:
        dele.append([row[2], row[4])
        print([row[2], row[4]])

with open('out.csv', 'w+') as j:
    writecsv.csvwriter(j)
    writecsv.writerows(dele)
```

This produced output:

```
MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,0
MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,0
MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,0
MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,0
MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,0
MyNetwork.node[0].nic.phy,0
MyNetwork.node[0].appl,3
MyNetwork.node[0].appl,0
MyNetwork.node[0].appl,0
MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,1.188e+07
MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,1232.22
MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,-1
MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,55.7565
MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,1
MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,0
MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,1232.22
MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,0
MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,0
MyNetwork.node[0].batteryStats,0
```

Also, unrelated to your issue at hand, the following code is unnecessary:

```
f.close()
j.close()
```

The reason why `with open(...):` syntax is so widely used, is because it handles gracefully closing the file for you. You don't need to separately close it yourself. As soon as the `with` block ends, the file will be closed.

Comment: @xgord Thanks but I have revised the question, I mistakenly wrote the row, but what i actually want is column 2 and column 3 to be written to a new file, please revise your answer, Thanks you once again

Comment: @SaleemRaza edited. In the future, please look over your question before you submit to make sure it's asking what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

It makes working with csv files very easy.

```
import pandas as pd #standard convention for importing pandas

# reads the csv file into a pandas dataframe
dataframe = pd.read_csv('saleem.csv') 

# make a new dataframe with just columns 2 and 4 
print_dataframe = dataframe.iloc[:,[2,4]] 

# output the csv file, but don't include the index numbers or header, just the data
print_dataframe.to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

If you use Ipython or Jupyter Notebook, you can type

```
dataframe.head()
```

to see the first few values of the dataframe. There is a lot more you can do with the library that might be worth learning, but in general it is a great way to read in, filter, and process csv data.